# Error when sending message to Bloomberg via QuickFixJ

Tags: bloomberg, quickfixj

I'm trying to sending packet type X to Bloomberg via QuickFixJ. I'm able to connect successfully but when I send the packet, I receive an error message :

```
8=FIXT.1.1^A9=160^A35=X^A34=4^A49=ARHGBETA^A52=20210915-13:16:04.156^A56=BBGBETA^A1022=****^A22=1^A48=BQ4434677^A268=2^A279=0^A269=0^A270=99.00357818603516^A279=0^A269=1^A270=99.01358032226562^A10=060^A
8=FIXT.1.1^A9=253^A35=j^A49=BBGBETA^A56=ARHGBETA^A34=4^A52=20210915-13:16:04.380^A45=4^A372=X^A380=0^A58=Validation failed for incoming X packet:
In mDIncGrp: In groupMDEntries[0]: NULL component instrument_MarketData
In groupMDEntries[1]: NULL component instrument_MarketData
```

And yet, I don't see how to define the component instrument_MarketData. I'm using the following code to generate the groups:

```
/**
 * Méthode de création d'un nouveau prix pour le publier sur Bloomberg
 * @param marketPrice
 * */
public MarketDataIncrementalRefresh createMarketDataIncrementalRefresh(MarketPrice marketPrice) {

    quickfix.fix50sp2.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh message = new MarketDataIncrementalRefresh();

    quickfix.fix50sp2.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries group = new MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries();

    message.getHeader().setString(1022, "****");

    quickfix.fix50sp2.component.MDIncGrp mdIncGrp = new MDIncGrp();

    mdIncGrp.setString(48, marketPrice.getCUSIP());

    mdIncGrp.setString(22, "1");

    Instrument instrument =new Instrument();
    /**
     * Ajout prix Bid au message
     * */
    instrument.setString(279, "0");
    instrument.setString(269, "0");
    instrument.setString(270, marketPrice.getBid_kech().toString());
    group.set(instrument);
    mdIncGrp.addGroup(group);

    /**
     * Ajout prix Ask au message
     * */
    instrument.setString(279, "0");
    instrument.setString(269, "1");
    instrument.setString(270, marketPrice.getAsk_kech().toString());
    group.set(instrument);
    mdIncGrp.addGroup(group);

    message.set(mdIncGrp);

    return message;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I define a custom dictionary to be able to send the message or can I do it with the default dictionary?

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a custom dictionary to **send** custom messages. Dictionary validation is only done for **received** messages, so you might need to alter your dictionary to successfully receive the responses sent by your counterparty.

As to your problem: the error sounds as if something is missing in your group regarding the instrument. Looking at your code I think you mix up the group stuff a bit. I posted this link for an earlier question of you: https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/repeating_groups.html

I think the important part is that you should add the group to the message like so:

```
quickfix.fix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries group =
  new quickfix.fix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries();

group.set(new MDEntryType('0'));
group.set(new MDEntryPx(12.32));
group.set(new MDEntrySize(100));
group.set(new OrderID("ORDERID"));
message.addGroup(group);      // important part
```

In your code you are adding a group to a group (`mdIncGrp.addGroup(group)`) and do a `message.set(mdIncGrp)` where you really should use `addGroup()`. Because of this the `48/SecurityID` field does not end up in the `MDIncGrp` but the root message.

```
8=FIXT.1.1^....removed...^A22=1^A48=BQ4434677^A268=2^A279=0^A269=0^A270=99.00357818603516^A279=0^A269=1^A270=99.01358032226562^A10=060^A
                                 ^^^ 48 is here where it should really
                                      be in each of these groups starting with delimiter tag 279
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I'm trying it out. I would like to understand in the doc Bloomberg provide, they state the components MdIncGrp and instrument_MarketData are required to send a message how does quickfixj figures out that these components exist if they are not defined explicitly?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your question. :)

Comment: In the Bloomberg doc, there is a table with the required fields. instrument_MarketData and MdIncGrp are marked <component name="..." required="Y"> so I would like to know how the acceptor finds these components if they are not explicitly defined in the message! Thanks!

Comment: The components are defined in the data dictionary. When compiling QFJ it takes the dictionary and generates the classes based on the dictionary.

Comment: Okay very clear thank you very much for your help !!